# Does starting a new transaction forces the current transaction to commit?

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, commit, autocommit

I have server that uses transactions to write data to database and if all the queries are successful it will commit otherwise it will rollback. Now I want to have two instances of the server work at the same time on the same database and tables.

When I was reading mysql's transaction documentation I noticed this sentence: "Beginning a transaction causes any pending transaction to be committed". Does this mean that if server A start transaction A and while transaction A is not completed yet, the server B start transaction B, transaction A is forced to commit? This doesn't make sense to me. If this is the case how I can insure that transaction B is not executed until transaction A is completed normally?
Would SET autocommit = 0 be an alternative to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming when you say you want two instances of the server to work at the same time you mean two separate sessions running on the same server.

The sentence "Beginning a transaction causes any pending transaction to be committed" refers to any pending transaction within the same session only. From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html

> The statements listed in this section (and any synonyms for them) implicitly end any transaction active in the current session, as if you had done a COMMIT before executing the statement.

So, if Session B starts a transaction before Session A is committed it will not force Session A to commit.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE super(id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> START TRANSACTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO super VALUE(1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> START TRANSACTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM super;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

***Starting the next transaction implicitly commits the previous pending transaction only in the same session on MySQL.***

For example, there is **`person` table** with **`id`** and **`name`** on **MySQL** as shown below.

#### `person` table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | **John** |
| **2** | **Tom** |

First, with **only one command prompt(with the same session)**, you take these steps with **the default isolation level `REPEATABLE READ`** on **MySQL** as shown below:

| Flow | Command Prompt 1(CP1) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`mysql -u root -p`** | **CP1 logs in MySQL.** |
| **Step 2** | **`USE test`** | **CP1 uses `test` database.** |
| **Step 3** | **`BEGIN;`** | **CP1 starts a transaction.** |
| **Step 4** | **`SELECT * FROM person;`** **1 John** **2 Tom** | **CP1 reads `person` table.** |
| **Step 5** | **`UPDATE person set name = "Lisa" where id = 2;`** | **CP1 updates `Tom` to `Lisa`.** |
| **Step 6** | **`BEGIN;`** | **Now, CP1 starts the next transaction so the previous pending transaction is implicitly committed in the same session.** |
| **Step 7** | **`ROLLBACK;`** | **CP1 rollbacks.** |
| **Step 8** | **`ROLLBACK;`** | **CP1 rollbacks again.** |
| **Step 9** | **`SELECT * FROM person;`** **1 John** **2 Lisa** | **CP1 reads `person` table.** #### `Lisa` is not rollbacked to `Tom` so starting the next transaction implicitly commits the previous pending transaction in the same session. |

Second, with **two command prompts(with two different sessions)**, you take these steps with **the default isolation level `REPEATABLE READ`** on **MySQL** as shown below:

| Flow | Command Prompt 1(CP1) | Command Prompt 2(CP2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`mysql -u root -p`** |  | **CP1 logs in MySQL.** |
| **Step 2** |  | **`mysql -u root -p`** | **CP2 logs in MySQL.** |
| **Step 3** | **`USE test`** |  | **CP1 uses `test` database.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`USE test`** | **CP2 uses `test` database.** |
| **Step 5** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **CP1 starts a transaction.** |
| **Step 6** | **`SELECT * FROM person;`** **1 John** **2 Tom** |  | **CP1 reads `person` table.** |
| **Step 7** | **`UPDATE person set name = "Lisa" where id = 2;`** |  | **CP1 updates `Tom` to `Lisa`.** |
| **Step 8** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **Now, CP2 starts the next transaction but the previous pending transaction in CP1's different session is not implicitly committed.** |
| **Step 7** | **`ROLLBACK;`** |  | **CP1 rollbacks.** |
| **Step 8** |  | **`ROLLBACK;`** | **CP2 rollbacks.** |
| **Step 9** | **`SELECT * FROM person;`** **1 John** **2 Tom** |  | **CP1 reads `person` table.** #### `Lisa` is rollbacked to `Tom` so starting the next transaction in a different session doesn't implicitly commits the previous pending transaction in a different session. |